# How to read file as String in Flutter that has been written to filesystem using NSKeyedArchiver in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, flutter, dart, nskeyedarchiver

After updating **iOS** native app with an app written on **Flutter** I want to read a file from filesystem on **iOS** device using **Dart**. The file I want to read has been previously written to filesystem using this `ObjectiveC` code:

```
- (void)setAccount:(FTAccountModel *)account {
    _account = account;
    NSString *path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
    path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:AccountModelPath];
    if (account) {
        NSArray * array = @[account];
        [array writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
        [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:array toFile:path];
    }
}
```

I've tried the following approach in **Flutter** using [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) package:

```
final appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final accountDataFile = File('${appDocDir.path}/$_iosAccountDataFile');
String contents = await accountDataFile.readAsString();
print("contents: $contents");
```

But I get an error when calling `readAsString()` method:

```
FileSystemException: Failed to decode data using encoding 'utf-8', path = '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FBCB4862-E5EA-4C93-8C2E-3DF1F00A8645/Documents/AccountModel.data'
```

How to read file on **iOS** device using `Dart` and `Flutter`, that has been written using `NSKeyedArchiver`?

Comment: did you found a solution for you question, I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of writing this answer, there are no plugins to read the file, that has been previously written to the filesystem using `NSKeyedArchiver` in iOS. The way to read the file is to [write custom platform-specific code](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels).

So the iOS platform code on **Swift** will be something like the following:

```
private func callGetUserIdFromNativeApp(result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
    var account: FTAccountModel?
    let fm = FileManager.default
    let urls = fm.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    if (!urls.isEmpty) {
        let file = urls[0].appendingPathComponent("Accounts.data", isDirectory: false)
        
        if (fm.fileExists(atPath: file.path)) {
            if let accountArray: [FTAccountModel] = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: file.path) as? [FTAccountModel] {
        
                if (!accountArray.isEmpty) {
                    account = accountArray[0]
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    if let userId: Int = account?.userId {
        result(String(userId))
    } else {
        result(nil)
    }
}
```

And the flutter part will use `MethodChannel` to invoke the native code:

```
static const MethodChannel _channel = const MethodChannel("CHANNEL_NAME");

static Future<String> getUserIdFromNativeIos() async {
  try {
    return await _channel.invokeMethod("METHOD_NAME");
  } catch (e){
    return _failedString();
  }
}
```